# What bags will fit a Challenge Seiran SL?

Tags: bags, recumbent, luggage

I own a Challenge Seiran SL (the 26" lightweight version of [this](http://www.challengebikes.com/seiran_detail.php)). For some short multidays trips I need to attach some form of bags. What are the available bags that will fit?

[image: Challenge Seiran SL]

[Full size picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYGSw.jpg)

For an other recumbent I already have a pair of [Ortlieb recumbent bags](http://www.ortlieb.com/_prod.php?lang=en&produkt=recumbentbag) but they attach to a rear rack and I do not see how I could attach a rack to my Seiran… Or is it possible?

Edit: The Seiran SL is not pictured on the web page. You can see it in the [Chanllenge Product Guide](http://www.challengebikes.com/brochures.php) on page 18.

Comment: Doesn't Challenge sell both a short rack and a Voyager rack that will fit the Seiran?

Comment: @R.Chung This is the *lightweith* Seiran. on the page I linked it is the third picture. I believe the rack they sell is for the regular (touring) version. On my frame I do not see anywhere to attache a rack.

Comment: It's hard to navigate that site, and I can't see any detailed pictures of the areas I'm trying to look at on the bike. Since they're handmade bikes, I assume no two are exactly the same, anyways. It seems there are two rack choices listed on the site, which mount to the back and/or sides of the seat, not to the frame. Can you attach some pictures of those areas of *your* bike?

Comment: @R.Chung My bad. The Seiran SL is not on any of these pictures.

Comment: @freiheit Picture attached.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking through the [Challenge Bikes product guide](http://www.challengebikes.com/brochures.php), it looks like the Seiran SL is not intended to be able to have any kind of rack on it.

Maybe you should talk to the dealer you bought the bike from. It looks to me like replacing the lightweight carbon seat with the aluminum seat option might make it possible to mount the Day Rack or Voyager Rack...

Would 15–30 liters be enough capacity? There's various bags designed to hang from the top of a recumbent seat, which would probably work:

- [Arkel Recumbent Seat Bag](http://www.arkel-od.com/us/recumbent-seat-bag.html)
- [Radical Design Universal Aero](https://www.radicaldesign.nl/en/products/recumbent-bags/rear-bags/universal-aero)
- [Radical Design Rackbag L](https://www.radicaldesign.nl/en/products/recumbent-bags/rear-bags/rackbag-l)

In addition, [here](https://www.radicaldesign.nl/en/which-panniers-fit-my-recumbent/challenge-seiran-sl) is a link to a page from the Radical Design site which lists bags that will fit the Seiran SL.

Comment: 15L would be too small. Maybe I could do with 30L, but it will be the strict minimum. I’ll have a look at your links. I attached a picture of the bike.

Comment: Indeed it is not intended to fit a rack. I am looking for a *bag*. This is a second hand bike so I have no particular dealer yet. But I will surely contact one soon. Looking at the pictures from Challenge’s site I do not think the SL can easily be fitted with the aluminium seat. It seems this seat is fitted on a tube that attach to the frame on a eyelet on the horizontal part of the main tube. The SL does not have this eyelet but a pair of them each side apart the rear wheel to attach the seat. See this on the picture of my bike.

Comment: Ah yes, the Banana racer, in addition to the small backpack I hacked, should do the trick. Thank you for the pointers.

Comment: Looks to me like a [Banana Racer](https://www.radicaldesign.nl/en/products/recumbent-bags/side-panniers/banana-racer) and [Solo Aero Narrow](https://www.radicaldesign.nl/en/products/recumbent-bags/rear-bags/solo-aero-narrow-blue) together would give you 37 liters carrying capacity, which is about one medium-sized pannier's capacity...

Comment: Yes. But as you can see on the picture, I already managed to attach a small (~10L) bag on the back of the seat. So the Solo Aero would not bring much. I’ll dig into the Banana though.

Answer (score 1):

The bike in your picture has a rack on the back no? If you can't fit the low riding ortlieb recumbants (due to their length) I'd recommend ortlieb front panniers (smaller than their rear counterparts and therefore more likely to fit that small rack. Also all Ortlieb bags have adjustable clips (so you can make them fit smaller/bigger racks).

Comment: My bad. The Seiran SL is not on the pictures on the web page I linked. You can see it in the catalogue, see my edit.

Comment: I attached a picture of my bike.