# Challenge Seiran luggage rack image or blueprint

Tags: frames, recumbent, luggage

Years ago, I bought a Challenge Seiran. At the time, I didn't bother buying the luggage rack attachment. Not the one attached behind the seat but the one going under it.
For those who don't know, it allows to attach big bags to secure them under the rider.
They look like the bags pictured in the following image.

[image]

I was trying to buy those attachments now but the Challenge website is dead since 2012. On top of that, it relies heavily on Flash which is not supported anymore. So I cannot buy it let alone see it.

I would like to replicate it but I will need to have some visual to figure out how I can machine it. Any picture, dimensions, blueprint will be appreciated.

Comment: Not a duplicate, but related   https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/13468/what-bags-will-fit-a-challenge-seiran-sl

Comment: Clarify - you're after the bag or the hardpoints that mount the bag to the bent?   Do you have a bag already?

Comment: I do not have the bag yet. I am looking for the hardpoints. I found a reseller for the bag. But I might do it myself.

Comment: I kinda got the flash working but its not a lot of use.     Start by downloading the .swf file from    http://www.challenge-recumbents.com//flash/seirandrager.swf   and open https://ruffle.rs/demo/   then "upload"   but this only gives a single static image of low resolution.

Comment: https://flasharch.com/en/downloads  works about the same - I used a linux deb but its windows and mac as well.   You might have more luck ?    Seems there are only 11 frames of images in it so probably not that useful.

Answer (score 1):

Based on page 4 of  http://www.challengebikes.com/pdfs/bap/folder2009en.pdf  the large-capacity rack offered was called a "voyager rack" and held four panniers.

[image]

The lower pair seem similar to this Terra-cycle rack found at https://t-cycle.com/products/challenge-seiran-rack

[image]

However I can't see how that would hold the upper two panniers pictured.  Perhaps there's a second similar structure cantilevered out of the rear of the seat-back ?

---

Separately, I can't see how your pictured red and black bag would attach anywhere.  If it hangs under the main frame, then there's nothing to stop it wobbling side to side unless the hardpoints are some kind of sideways outriggers.

Additionally the chain is exposed all down the right-side of the frame, and you don't want that dragging on the bag at any point.

Comment: The bags in the picture are holding onto the bike using gravity. The top loops are attached either on the seat or the post. I remember there was some kind of structure attached underneath to stop the side way motion of the bags. This structure was not there to support the weight but to stop the wobbling and protect the chain.